# Error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter/material.dart'. (uri_does_not_exist at [myapp] test/widget_test.dart:8)

Tags: flutter, dart

I made an app in Flutter and there are no errors on its Dart file but I suddenly end up with errors on `widget_test.dart`. can you guys help me out. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And don't spam irrelevant tags!

Comment: Try running `flutter pub get` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter clean`, and then `flutter pub get` in the terminal respectively.

If that doesn't work, try running `flutter upgrade`, and then repeating the initial steps.

Finally, if it still isn't working, you can run `flutter doctor` to see if there's anything glaringly wrong with your project.